# How to dispatch custom messages across Javascript classes in an efficient way?

Tags: javascript, performance, events, publish-subscribe

I have built loosely coupled components for a javascript client application where these components send and receive messages via a manager class:

```
a component detects an event => send to manager 

manager receives an event => send to everyone 

any component got message => interested in message? yes: process, no: discard.
```

This works as intended, but not efficient. Here is the implementation of manager:

in Livescript:

```
class mgr
  ~> 
    @actor-list = []

  register: (actor) -> 
    @actor-list ++= [actor]

  dispatch: (msg) -> 
    for actor in @actor-list
      actor.inbox-put msg
```

in Javascript:

```
var mgr;
mgr = (function(){
  mgr.displayName = 'mgr';
  var prototype = mgr.prototype, constructor = mgr;
  function mgr(){
    var this$ = this instanceof ctor$ ? this : new ctor$;
    this$.actorList = [];
    return this$;
  } function ctor$(){} ctor$.prototype = prototype;
  prototype.register = function(actor){
    return this.actorList = this.actorList.concat([actor]);
  };
  prototype.dispatch = function(msg){
    var i$, ref$, len$, actor, results$ = [];
    for (i$ = 0, len$ = (ref$ = this.actorList).length; i$ < len$; ++i$) {
      actor = ref$[i$];
      results$.push(actor.inboxPut(msg));
    }
    return results$;
  };
  return mgr;
}());
```

I have searched the net for "event dispatching in Javascript" and there is a couple of projects used for this purpose, but some of them seems dead:

- https://github.com/mrdoob/eventdispatcher.js/

Some of them uses same `for loop` under the hood:

- https://github.com/krasimir/EventBus

and some of them requires binding on an html node:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

What I need is pure javascript communication between Javascript classes. Is there any efficient/native way to achieve this?

Comment: I remember trying to find a clean answer to this question before switching to TypeScript and using Interfaces (i.e. I never found a solution I really loved)

Comment: I think Pub/Sub, which is essentially what you are implementing here, is the most robust real time solution, async implementations allow you to avoid some of the headache (and overhead) of pub/sub, but its a redesign not a simple change

Comment: I didn't really get it, do you suggest https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS or something else? Redesign is not a matter...

Comment: My apologies, the reason I upvoted your question but wrote a comment and not an answer is that I think it's a fair question, but I dont think there is a clear answer.

Comment: Here is my advice: Is your application overhead **really** large enough to be worried about this? If the solution works and is fast enough for your purposes, put optimization aside for now. Software Development is about making useful, functional and hopefully bug free applications, not about writing the most efficient code. Our customers should not be *other developers* our customers should be our users and/or clients, and is about making sure THEY are happy at all times

Comment: I appreciate your considerations. The application really needs to be performant, since it'll be used for large SCADA systems. [Here](https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-website) is the source codes and [here](https://aktos-elektronik.com/test/#demos) live demos page. Since there are numerous widgets on the same page, page seems non responsive. There might be some other hacks to achieve this, such as updating only widgets seen on the screen or so.

Comment: Motivation of my question: Once I stucked on  a high-frequency-generator code with a microcontroller. At the end, solution was simple: there was a PWM driver built into the microcontroller for this purpose. I used that device with a couple of settings and everything went fine. I wonder if there is such infrastructure in javascript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89369/discussion-between-leemo-and-ceremcem).